# Discarding small eigenvalues to bound rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, upper-lower-bounds, nuclear-norm

Suppose I have a diagonal matrix $D$ with nonnegative entries on the diagonal $\lambda_i$. Let the rank of $D$ be $r$. I am promised that $1-\delta \leq \sum_i\lambda_i \leq 1$ for some $0\leq\delta< 1$.

I am allowed to create a new matrix $D'$ that satisfies the following properties

1. $D'$ is obtained by setting some of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ to zero.
2. $\|D' - D\|_1 \leq \varepsilon$

Is it possible to bound the rank of $D'$ in the following way (or something similar)?

$$\text{rank}(D') \leq f(\varepsilon, \delta)\left(\sum_i\lambda_i^{1/2}\right)^2,$$

where $f(\varepsilon, \delta)$ is some "reasonable" function e.g. $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ that doesn't depend on the rank itself. The summation on the right hand side above is over all the eigenvalues of $D$.

---

My attempted solution:

I decided to discard the smallest eigenvalues. If $\lambda_i\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{r}$, I will replace them with $0$. This ensures that $\|D' - D\|_1\leq \varepsilon$ and intuitively seems right since it lowers the rank as much as possible. However, I am struggling to lower bound $\left(\sum_i\lambda_i^{1/2}\right)^2$.